# is there any way to monitor resources used by my Jupyter notebook in visual studio code?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science, monitoring

recently, I fell in love with jupyter notebook in vs-code. but I got into trouble while I was trying to profile my code. I was looking for something similar as in google-colab or even the original browser base jupyter-nb. I'm actually asking about some extensions or options or even cell(s) of code that can approximately give me some information about resources (such as ROM, RAM,...) by my nb?